# Git push fast-forward issue

Tags: git, github

I am trying to push my code to GitHub and it is giving me errors.

I have tried

```
git add .
git commit -m "blah"
git push origin master
git push --force
```

all with no success.

```
Georges-MacBook-Pro-2:meetlete georgeconnolly$ git push --set-upstream origin main
To https://github.com/grobconnolly/meetlete.git
 ! [rejected]        main -> main (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/grobconnolly/meetlete.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

[image]

Comment: Did you read and understand the green text prefixed with "hint"?

Comment: yes, but i dont know how to fix it,

Comment: Can you first run `git fetch` and then show a screenshot of `gitk --all` (or equivalent representation of the relevant parts of the commit graph)?

Comment: Georges-MacBook-Pro-2:meetlete georgeconnolly$ git fetch
Georges-MacBook-Pro-2:meetlete georgeconnolly$ git -all
unknown option: -all
usage: git [--version] [--help] [-C <path>] [-c <name>=<value>]
           [--exec-path[=<path>]] [--html-path] [--man-path] [--info-path]
           [-p | --paginate | -P | --no-pager] [--no-replace-objects] [--bare]
           [--git-dir=<path>] [--work-tree=<path>] [--namespace=<name>]
           <command> [<args>]
Georges-MacBook-Pro-2:meetlete georgeconnolly$

Comment: Not `git -all`, but `gitk --all`.

Comment: Georges-MacBook-Pro-2:meetlete georgeconnolly$ gitk --all
-bash: gitk: command not found
Georges-MacBook-Pro-2:meetlete georgeconnolly$

Answer (score 1):

Try to do a **git pull**, seem like your branch is not updated

Comment: There is no tracking information for the current branch.
Please specify which branch you want to merge with.
See git-pull(1) for details.

    git pull <remote> <branch>

If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:

    git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> main

Georges-MacBook-Pro-2:meetlete georgeconnolly$

Comment: Try : git pull origin master

Comment: or : or git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/master master 
git pull

Comment: Georges-MacBook-Pro-2:meetlete georgeconnolly$ git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/master master
Branch 'master' set up to track remote branch 'master' from 'origin'.
Georges-MacBook-Pro-2:meetlete georgeconnolly$ git pull
There is no tracking information for the current branch.
Please specify which branch you want to merge with.
See git-pull(1) for details.

    git pull <remote> <branch>

If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:

git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> main

Georges-MacBook-Pro-2:meetlete georgeconnolly$

Comment: what is the result of : git branch -a

Comment: Georges-MacBook-Pro-2:meetlete georgeconnolly$ git branch -a
* main
  master
  remotes/origin/main
  remotes/origin/master
Georges-MacBook-Pro-2:meetlete georgeconnolly$

Comment: git branch --set-upstream-to origin/master or git branch --set-upstream-to remotes/origin/master

Comment: and then you can git pull and git push your code